# state is not changing in react. It changes the state after browser refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, local-storage

I have a button on the screen.
on click of that button, I am toggling the database values between 0 and 1.
and on database value 1 I want to show button as ONLINE and on database value 0 I want to display button as OFFLINE.
I am also using local storage to persist in the state. But still, the state isn't getting toggled.

CODE

Here is how I am setting the database value in local storage

```
dispatch({ type: SHOP_STATUS_LOAD, payload: '' })
        Axios.patch('http://localhost:5000/api/shopuser/shop/status', null, { headers })
            .then((resp) => {
                dispatch({ type: SHOP_STATUS_FETCH, payload: resp.data.message })
                var status
                resp.data.data.forEach(element => {
                    status = element.shopStatus
                });
                localStorage.setItem('status', JSON.stringify(status))
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err)
                dispatch({
                    type: SHOP_STATUS_ERROR,
                    payload: "Unable to get data. Try again.",
                })
            });
```

my button page code

```
const Home = (props) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [test, setTest] = React.useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('status')));

  const { getCurrentOrders, setShopStatus } = props

  useEffect(() => {
    getCurrentOrders()
    const socket = openSocket('http://localhost:5000')
    socket.on('orders', data => {
      getCurrentOrders(data)
    })
    setTest(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('status')))
    return () => socket.disconnect();
  }, [])

        <Grid container justify="flex-start" className={classes.newSection}>
          <Button variant="outlined" color={test === 1 ? `primary` : `secondary`} onClick={handleClickOpen} className={test === 1 ? `classes.buttonOnline` : `classes.buttonOffline`}>
            {test === 1 ? 'Online' : 'Offline'}
          </Button>
        </Grid>
```

Comment: did u pass the `[setTest]` in `useEffect` and tried ?

Comment: `setTest ` is already in `useeffect` @RajKumar

Comment: can you add the code for `handleClickOpen` ?

Comment: `const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };`
just setting another state in it. @k.s.

Comment: @SagarChavan you have to check whether `setTest` is triggering after the localstorage is update in the redux.

Comment: u mean I should get the value that is 1 or 0 in the redux state and then compare in button  ? @RajKumar

Comment: No, you just make sure, your localstorage update is triggred before you get and placed in setTest, i didn't clearly understand when the database call is triggered

Comment: A model pops up on button click. When i click YES in that modal. it dispatches the action and calls the API and the database value gets toggoled.